# SQL Server CTP installer - The application cannot find one of its required files

Tags: sql-server

I have downloaded the exe file to install SQL Server 2016 CTP4.

When I run the exe, it gives me the following message:

```
The application cannot find one of its required files, possibly because it was unable to create it in the folder.  Please make sure that the folder in which this application was downloaded is accessible and not read-only.
```

Why isn't the file running the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't properly read the instructions.

```
This download has multiple files.
```

I needed to download ALL FILES listed on the website, not just the exe.

Downloading the other .box file listed into the same directory resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found very same issue faced by OP while installing Visual Studio 2017. I had downloaded the bootstrap exe from MSDN which kicks off the download and install process. I faced this error even though my user account was an administrator on the target machine.

Looking at the error I gave full access to `everyone` user on the folder in which the setup file was present. It worked after that. You can accomplish it from `Security` tab in `Properties` window for any directory. I was able to do it easily as I was working in a private Hyper-V lab. Changing the access rights on a PC in corporate environment might require additional help from your IT support team.

Many a times running the setup exe with administrative privileges also solves the issue. Most MS installers always require administrative privileges as they've to alter system registry and copy data in %programfiles% directory. If you want to try this route then right click the installer file > Select `Run as administrator` option from context menu.